# This is a query permission sql, which is used to query the database. How can this sql be optimized?

Tags: sql

This is a query using a union join, with roles, permission tables and some other intermediate tables.I think it has some repetitions, how can I optimize it, or can I just change to another way of writing it?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    menu.perm_key 
FROM
    user_role
    LEFT JOIN role ON user_role.role_id = role.id
    LEFT JOIN role_menu ON user_role.role_id = role_menu.role_id
    LEFT JOIN menu ON menu.id = role_menu.menu_id 
WHERE
    user_role.user_id = 1 
    AND role.`status` = 1 
    AND menu.`status` = 1 

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    role.role_key 
FROM
    user_role
    LEFT JOIN role ON user_role.role_id = role.id 
WHERE
    user_role.user_id = 1 
    AND role.`status` = 1
```

Below is the result of using`SELECT DISTINCT role_key, perm_key from ...`

| role_key | perm_key |
| --- | --- |
| user | create_order |
| user | update_info |

I expect it to become

| key_info |
| --- |
| user |
| create_order |
| update_info |

Comment: Now I'm curious where this data is going. In the domain I work in, this result would be useless, or more easily used by taking the 3 pieces of information as a single row (i.e., a single Object in an OOP language). As I mentioned in my answer, it's really unusual to combine "different types of things" into a single column; that's partly why the solution is not easy to arrive at.

Comment: I don't know if you are using java, this requirement is a permission check in a springsecurity. Because the methods of verifying roles and verifying permissions call the same method, I need to put the role and permission information together.

Comment: As it happens, I work on a Spring app that uses SpringSecurity. We also have roles and permissions. SpringSecurity is not my forte, but from what I know and understand, I'd still be returning this data in a single row as some POJO. Then, access instance's data via getters.

Comment: I am also not familiar with springsecurity. The methods `hasRole` and `hasAuthority` called with the annotation `@PreAuthorize` will use the same collection. I think that means roles and permissions are the same. So put it into the same collection after querying in the database

Comment: Ours are too, but they are declared as static constants for reference in `@PreAuthorize`. For the users, we pull a list of all permissions with their granted status. (Made the mistake of looking at this from my phone, so not prepared. Comment back or message and I’ll continue looking when I’m at my computer.)

Comment: Do you not have the need to query authorities and roles at the same time?

Comment: Like I said, SpringSecurity isn't something I know a lot about, but what I see is just a few fetches. One for the user profile (simple data like name, hashed password, etc), one for their permissions (this could actually be multiple queries), and one for a "login response." That said, since this has quickly diverged into a non-SQL question, I should probably recommend that you research SpringSecurity or start a new question tagged for that part of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Based on the information in the comments, I'm updating my response.

Needing the two columns to return in one column, the only other way I see is to use some sort of function. I'm going with `IF` here, but `COALESCE` could work as well.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    IF(menu.perm_key IS NOT NULL, menu.perm_key, role.role_key) as key
FROM
    user_role
    LEFT JOIN role ON user_role.role_id = role.id
    LEFT JOIN role_menu ON user_role.role_id = role_menu.role_id
    LEFT JOIN menu ON menu.id = role_menu.menu_id 
WHERE
    user_role.user_id = 1 
    AND role.`status` = 1 
    AND menu.`status` = 1
```

---

**Original Answer**

Without more information, the only thing I see is that the `UNION` appears to be unnecessary.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    menu.perm_key, role.role_key
FROM
    user_role
    LEFT JOIN role ON user_role.role_id = role.id
    LEFT JOIN role_menu ON user_role.role_id = role_menu.role_id
    LEFT JOIN menu ON menu.id = role_menu.menu_id 
WHERE
    user_role.user_id = 1 
    AND role.`status` = 1 
    AND menu.`status` = 1
```

Unless you expected these values as separate rows, this should work fine. If you are expecting separate rows, I would question why. To me, each row should represent "the same thing" as any other row, but with different values. By using separate rows, one row represents the "perm key" while the next represents the "role key." Even if these point to the same object type or enum, they have different uses and I would therefore consider them as "different things" and not appropriate to return on separate rows. This would be especially true and awkward to work with if your query returns more than 2 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would have expected the different columns to return to the same list. I recognize that this is indeed an abnormal requirement. I will take another approach in terms of code logic.

Comment: @QyStart, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I updated the details of the question and the new query results are the same as the previous ones.